# What is this event in probability?

Tags: probability

Let ${H_j}$  denote the event that flip $j,j \ge 1$, lands heads, and ${C_i}$  is the event that coin $i$  was chosen, $i = 1,2$ .
Given, probability of coin 1 landing head is 0.3, and that of coin 2 is 0.5.
In one of the parts to this question, I am asked to find $P\left( {{H_2}{H_3}{H_4}|{H_1}} \right)$.

What event is this ${{H_2}{H_3}{H_4}}$ event. Successive heads in next three turns after first flip?

Yes its the correct interpretation!
Answer is below:
$\begin{array}{c}
P\left( {{H_2}{H_3}{H_4}|{H_1}} \right) = \frac{{\frac{1}{2} \times ({{0.3}^4} + {{0.5}^4})}}{{0.40}}\\
 = 0.08825
\end{array}$

Answer (score 1):

Event that second, third and fourth are heads, given that the first is known to be heads. They omit the $``\cap"$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its the correct interpretation!
Answer is below:
$\begin{array}{c}
P\left( {{H_2}{H_3}{H_4}|{H_1}} \right) = \frac{{\frac{1}{2} \times ({{0.3}^4} + {{0.5}^4})}}{{0.40}}\\
 = 0.08825
\end{array}$